# Restrict solr search results in ibm WCS FEP6

Tags: solr, limit, restrict, wcs

I have requirement in IBM WCS FEP 6 solr, i want to restrict the solr results for a category/search page. ie  if the result is more than 300 it should show only 300 products and if there is filter called 'Red' and after applying this filter it should retrieve only the red products from this first 300 products

Answer (score 0):

The way you can restrict the number of search results is by setting the `maxRows` parameter in the search profile. Identify the search profile corresponding to your search and look it up in `wc-search.xml`. Set the below param in search profile

```
<_config:param name="maxRows" value="300"/>
```

I am not pretty sure on your requirement with filtering "red". If it is a custom field you will have to write a custom expression provider to add that filter query in the solr request

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 

maxRows will restrict only the results for a single hit. ie since we have lazy loading it will load the results even if the total results is more than 300. I want to restrict the total number of results to 300. 

We can stop the lazy loading after 300 through code but consider if the total result is 500 and in that Red products is 305, after applying the Red filter it will again show 300 red products which is wrong.